# Facebook and Twitter buttons not aligned

Tags: facebook, button, twitter

I display FB Like/Share and Twitter buttons on same line but they won't align vertically, see code below from our [What's New](http://www.ascendo-inc.com/datavault/mac/whats-new.html) page. I'm looking for a simple solution to vertically align all buttons.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.ascendo.co/mac-password-manager.html" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.ascendo.co/mac-password-manager.html" data-text="Check out DataVault Password Manager for Mac, the best way to secure your confidential information!" data-via="Ascendo" data-count="none">Tweet</a><script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a simple

`vertical-align: middle;` to the

```
#twitter-widget-0
```

Comment: Thanks Mark but I don't understand your explanation. There is no occurence of #twitter-widget-0" in code from Twitter or the code on my page.

Comment: Hi Marc, If you check out the your page with developer tools open, the Iframe which is generating the twitter button has an id of 'twitter-widget-0'. So adding '#twitter-widget-0' in your css and giving it the style of vertical-align: middle; it will vertically align it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.fb-like{
    Display:table-row;
}
```

Comment: Thanks wijaya but where exactly do I insert that code?

Comment: This is what worked for me (won't work on older browsers). `.fb-like {display: inline-flex !important;}`